# Selectively push items to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So if I had:

```
A=['a','b','c'];
B=[];

for (var i = 0;i<7;i++){
   B.push(A[i])
}
```

I would get

```
B=["a", "b", "c", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Instead I want

```
B= ["a","b","c"]
```

So I guess I would need something like

```
for (var i = 0;i<7;i++){
   B.push(A[i] "unless A[i] is undefined. Then don't push anything")
}
```

How would I do this in Javascript?

Comment: I believe you are looking for [`array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length). Where did you get 7 from?

Comment: Also, what if `A = ['a', undefined, 'b']`? What if `A = ['a',, 'b']`? Note that these two cases are subtly different.

Comment: umm, I would ideally be looking to forgo the push in every undefined case, regardless of order. I think the second case is a slightly different problem but probably has a similar solution.

Comment: Additionally, 7 was random. I just wanted to make the point that it was longer than 3 (length of A)

Comment: @Jon What is the difference? Empty commas still evaluate to undefined and for `A = [undefined, ]`, `A[0] === A[1]` is true.

Comment: @Daniel: If you have an `undefined` element then the array has the property e.g. "1" and its value is `undefined`. If you skip it completely then the array does not have the property "1", even though `A[1]` still evaluates to `undefined` (for the same reason that `A["lalalala"]` also evaluates to `undefined`). http://jsfiddle.net/f8g6S/

Comment: @Jon Wow that's crazy, thanks. For other's reference, this can be checked by using the `in` operator (`KEY in ARRAY`) or `hasOwnProperty(prop)` method of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An Object Oriented Aspect**

=> After that code, clean your array :

```
B.clean();
```

Known that clean is an extension of array Class(OOP context)

```
Array.prototype.clean=function(){
    var newArray = [];
    for(var index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
        if(this[index]) {
            newArray.push(this[index]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
};
```

Comment: What a neat solution.

Answer (score 9):

Some ES magic

```
    [1, 2, undefined].filter(Boolean)
```

will produce
`[1, 2]`

Comment: Just to be clear. `[0, '', null, 1, 2, undefined].filter(Boolean)` will also produce `[1, 2]`. I wanted to emphasize since the question focusses on stripping `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're searching:

[Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter/)

```
B = A.filter(function (element) {
    return element !== undefined;
});
```

That Code will make a duplicate of A filtering out all undefined elements.

Comment: Needs a polyfill for IE < 9, but this is definitely the best.

Comment: IE...pffff... IE always needs special treatment, we've word for that in German its called "Extrawurst" :D

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating the array and pushing elements one at a time to a new array, it's usually more efficient to use the [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function, like so:

```
var B = A.filter(function(item){ return item !== undefined; });
```

You may also want to be cautious about using **undefined**.  This is easily confused with other constructs such as **null** or empty strings.  If you use "!=" instead of "!==" in the function, that will filter out null or missing array items, as well as items which are set specifically as undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a safeguard like

```
A[i] && B.push(A[i])
```

which would only push if A[1](http://jsfiddle.net/cyLgd/) returns a `true`, but that would also give false if `A[i]` would be `0`

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyLgd/)

---

I would suggest checking against `null`

```
 if (A[i] != null) B.push(A[i])
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyLgd/1/)

---

If you want to keep your first `for`loop as it is you can "clean" the array after by using filter. Like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    B.push(A[i])
}
var clean_B = B.filter(function (item) {
    return item != null;
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyLgd/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You stated the answer to your question in your sort-of comment (use `//` at the end of the line next time, no need for inserting a comment in a string).

`unless A[i] is undefined. Then don't push anything`

Another way of putting it is, `if A[i] is not undefined, then push`.

When put like that, it directly translates into code.

```js
if (A[i] !== undefined)
{
    B.push(A[i]);
}
```

I elaborated on your comment to show you how easily you can figure these types of questions out with a little effort and time.

However, as others have stated, a much better way of ignoring undefined indices is to simply iterate to `A.length`, however this only works if there are no undefined values in-between the defined values (which is still likely the case).

Answer (score 0):

You would use an if statement

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    if (A[i] !== undefined) {
        B.push(A[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem would be solved by iterating from 1 to array.length, or by using a [for in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

If you're going to be dealing with arrays that could have undefined elements, for example `[0, undefined, 4]`, then you'd need to check if the element is defined before you add it. `if(a[i] !== undefined)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a *compact* function to filter out `undefined` values:

```
function compact(col) {
  return col.filter(function(val) {
    return val !== undefined;
  });
}

console.log(compact([false,0,1,null,undefined])); // [false,0,1,null]
```

JS Bin Example

**http://jsbin.com/mabowana/4/edit**

Comment: But he doesn't want to filter out *all* falsy values. Isn't that clear from the question?

Comment: You did, but it still filters out everything falsy because now it has a bug. And once that's fixed, this answer will be identical to two others.

Answer (score 0):

*initials:*

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
B = [];
```

---

I think, the closest answer to OP's question would be **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/rp45c7f6/)**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
   if (typeof A[i] !== "undefined") B.push(A[i]);
   else continue;
}
```

or **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/spas3mzk/)** one:

```
for (elem of A) if (typeof elem !== "undefined") B.push(elem); else continue;
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of hard coding `i < 7`, use `i < A.length`

```
for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
   B.push(A[i])
}
```